# How to list categories and subcategories in JSON format?

Tags: categories, json

I need to integrate [this plugin](http://kotowicz.net/jquery-option-tree/demo/demo.html) with my WordPress site, and the categories must be in  this format:

```
 "Option 1": {"Suboption":200},
 "Option 2": {"Suboption 2": {"Subsub 1":201, "Subsub 2":202},
                "Suboption 3": {"Subsub 3":203, "Subsub 4":204, "Subsub 5":205}
               }
```

How can I get that?
I tried the options of the [json-api](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/).

And this is the walker:

```
class MyWalker extends Walker_Category {
    var $tree_type = 'category';

    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return;

        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent:{";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return;

        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent}\n";
    }

    function start_el($output, $category, $depth , $args = array() ) {
        extract($args);
        $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $output .= '"' . $cat_name.'=>'.$depth . '",';
    }

    function end_el($output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return;

        $output .= "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you build your custom array and do a [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: @brasofilo It will change (categories), how can I make custom array dynamically?

Comment: I really don't understand what is the heart of the problem, what does that jQuery Option Tree has to do with the JsonAPI plugin or the `Walker_Category`... I think, in general sense, every line of code is `dynamic`, so once again: check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fast example using `get_categories` instead of a plugin or the walker class, maybe it will help you in the right direction, it will list all children of a parent category in json format. As brasofilo mentions since you require a specific format you will want to build a custom array.

```
// let's get the bare minimum going
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'child_of'                 =>  20, //change this, hardcoded as example
    'taxonomy'                 =>  'category'
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
$json = json_encode($categories);

var_dump($json); //do what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'parent' => 0
];

function _get_child_terms( $items ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
      $item->children = get_terms( 'category', array( 'child_of' => $item->term_id, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
      if ( $item->children ) _get_child_terms( $item->children );
    }
    return $items;
}

$terms = _get_child_terms( get_terms( $args ) );
echo json_encode( $terms );
```