# Get subcategories with JSON API plugin

Tags: plugins, categories, plugin-json-api

How to get subcategories with JSON API wordpress plugin?

I see how to get categories, but what is the way to get categories with subcategories at the same time? How should I modify the existing code?

```
public function get_category_index() {
    global $json_api;
    $args = null;
    if (!empty($json_api->query->parent)) {
      $args = array(
        'parent' => $json_api->query->parent
      );
    }
    $categories = $json_api->introspector->get_categories($args);
    return array(
      'count' => count($categories),
      'categories' => $categories
    );
 }
```

I know we have [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81895/how-to-list-categories-and-subcategories-in-json-format) which is not so comrehensible

Comment: If you are [referring to this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) (or the Chassis [integration on GitHub](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API)), then you are in the right place as this is the plugin version of what will get integrated into WP core. If not, then we can't help as 3rd party plugin or theme support is off topic here.

Comment: Yes, I am referring this plugin exactly

Comment: Have you already dumped the global and searched for functions and methods in core?

Comment: Yes, yet the question remains @kaiser

Comment: Please file an [edit] with your finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retrieving terms

With the current version of the "WP API" (JSON API plugin), there's a simple way to retrieve terms:

```
GET /taxonomies/<taxonomy>/terms
```

The method responsible is `get_taxonomy_terms( $taxonomy )` in the [plugins core](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/lib/class-wp-json-taxonomies.php#L204-L231).

You will have to check `is_wp_error()` on the return value to check if the taxonomy exists at the point where you invoke your own calls.

### Internals

As we are talking about a new core API currently running as plugin, it sticks close to core itself and uses `$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );` to retrieve the terms/taxons (categories, post tags, etc.) of a given taxonomy. The only default arg for that call is `hide_empty => true`.

### Filtering the returned terms #1)

Looking at the [core function internals](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1311), you will find a filter:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'get_terms_args', $args, $taxonomies );
```

So simply apply a callback to that filter. Be careful to not intercept other calls.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#163923) Alter term fetching args for the WP API/JSON plugin */

add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'remote_parent_terms_from_json_response', 10, 2 );
function remote_parent_terms_from_json_response( Array $args, Array $taxonomies )
{
    // Do not impact subsequent calls and remove the callback. Single running filter cb.
    if ( /* some case */ )
    {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        return wp_parse_args( array(
            // alter args in here
        ), $args );
    }

    // default case
    return $args;
}
```

### Filtering the returned terms #2)

Right after the call to the DB with `get_terms()`, the function loops through all fetched terms and "prepares" them for the JSONified return value using the [`prepare_taxonomy_term( $term )`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/lib/class-wp-json-taxonomies.php#L310-L342) method. This method has a filter at its very end:

```
return apply_filters( 'json_prepare_term', $data, $term, $context );
```

You could simply return `FALSE` or `NULL` if a taxonomy term does not fit in (for e.g. being a parent and having `parent => 0` set) and then run `array_filter( $terms )` on your returned data to remove all unset, false- or nullified terms.

This might be the easier solution that you want to use during prototyping. It as well is the more DB intensive solution as you first retrieve the terms from the DB and afterwards remove it, adding an additional overhead to your request.