# Retrieve list of taxonomies in json

Tags: taxonomy, json

I have custom taxonomies

like that

/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=my_cat&post_type=my_poet

I want retrieve list of taxonomies in json

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'json_handler'));
```

I tried

```
function json_handler(){
$categories = get_terms( 'my_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
print_r($categories);
}
```

Outpot

```
WP_Error Object ( [errors:WP_Error:private] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data:WP_Error:private] => Array ( ) )
```

But it working for normal category

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    print_r($categories);
```

Outpot

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 1 [name] => Uncategorized [slug] => uncategorized [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 1 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 ) )
```

Here is my_cat register_taxonomy

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy'));
function create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
// Labels part for the GUI
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Store  Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Store  Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Store  Categories ',$this -> textdomain ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Store Categories' ,$this -> textdomain),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Categories Name',$this -> textdomain ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
);
// Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
register_taxonomy('my_cat',$this->post_type,array(
'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'my_cat' ),
));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Related? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163923/get-subcategories-with-json-api-plugin

Comment: The error message says it all; your are using "my_cat" as taxonomy query var but it is not correct; or maybe the taxonomy is not registered as public. Can you post the code you are using to register the taxonomy?

Comment: @cybmeta the code here https://gist.github.com/abada/585934a14537e32eb26e

Comment: @Digitalchild I don`t using any plugin

Comment: Please, [add the relevant code in the question itself](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/189412/edit) so this question and answer can be a reference for future users; if you use a external service and it goes down this question and answer would lose the useful for people with the same problem.

Comment: @cybmeta i did :) , where the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your trying to access taxonomy data before it is registered.

**This doesn't work:**

```
add_action('init', 'json_handler');
function json_handler(){
    $categories = get_terms( 'my_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
        // encode the $categories array as json
        print_r( json_encode( $categories ) );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy');
function create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
    // Labels part for the GUI
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
        //Rest of your labels
    );
    // Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
    register_taxonomy('my_cat',$this->post_type,array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'my_cat' ),
    ));
}
```

**This works:**

```
add_action('init', 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy');
function create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
    // Labels part for the GUI
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
        //Rest of your labels
    );
    // Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
    register_taxonomy('my_cat',$this->post_type,array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'my_cat' ),
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'json_handler');
function json_handler(){
    $categories = get_terms( 'my_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
        // encode the $categories array as json
        print_r( json_encode( $categories ) );
    }
}
```

Change the order, as I did above, is not a good solution for maintainability. A better solution would be:

1.- Register the taxonomy on `init` with low priority (default priority is 10, actions with same priority are executed in the order they appear):

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy'), 1 );
```

2.- Try to access taxonomy data after `init` event, so you are sure the taxonomy has been registered, or on `init` events with priority higher than priority of taxonomy register callback, in this example with priority higher than 1.

**Note**: registering a taxonomy before or after `init` is not recommended.

Comment: thanks for your answer . I apply registering a taxonomy in separate file and json_handler in another file

Comment: In API.php 
`add_action('init', array($this, 'json_handler'),999);`

in stores.php
`add_action('init', array($this, 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy'),1);`

Doesn`t work :(

Comment: The tick is show custom taxonomies in json format by direct link form my plugin like this `?endpoint=my_cat`

Comment: The code I posted has been tested and the problem you described in the question was solved (the WP_Error message). What other problem do you have? Is still that error message appearing? If the problem now is another one, please describe it, maybe better in a separate question to stick with one question per thread.

Comment: yes you are right your answer working but no in my case , i will write another question

Comment: Note: I've edited the answer to inclue `json_encode` to print the `$categories` array in json format.

Comment: I am using wp_send_json() instead json_encode

Comment: Here is the new question link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189477/retrieve-custom-taxonomies

Comment: I will see the other question. Note that I can not know what you are using if you don't say. By the way, `wp_send_json()` should be used only on Ajax requests and direct/raw requests because it sends the response and close the application.

Comment: Yes i know and that exactly what i need , as before i used `json_encode($array);exit(); `