# Retrieve custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, json

I want to make plugin to make custom  taxonomies for custom post type

like

```
wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store_cat&post_type=store_kyd_app
```

and register this taxonomy at stores.php

```
public function __construct($textdomain, $version) {
if (is_admin()) {
add_action('init', array($this, 'create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy'),1);
}
}
function create_stores_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {
// Labels part for the GUI
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Store  Categories', $this -> textdomain ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Store  Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Store  Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Store  Categories ',$this -> textdomain ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Store Categories' ,$this -> textdomain),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Categories Name',$this -> textdomain ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Store Categories',$this -> textdomain ),
); 
// Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag
register_taxonomy('store_cat',$this->post_type,array(
'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'how_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'store_cat' ),
));
}
```

Now i want Retrieve custom taxonomies in json

Here is th ecode from api.php

```
public function __construct($textdomain, $version) {
add_action('init', array($this, 'json_handler'),999);
}

public function json_handler() {
  if($_GET['endpoint']=="categories"){
   $this->get_categories();
   }


 }

public function get_categories(){
     $categories = get_terms( 'store_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    wp_send_json($categories)

}
```

Output

```
null
```

why !!

Comment: What is `api.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're registering your taxonomy only if `is_admin` is true, so your taxonomy won't exist for any non-admin request. Taxonomies (and post types) have to be registered on every request.

Comment: Yes !!!! thanks it working after comment `is_admin`